How to find the axle kit for a Shimano front hub
Given a Shimano front hub how do I find the corresponding axle part numbers? Does anyone know where on Shimano's website I can find this information?
I have a Shimano front hub (Deore XT HB M8000, 36 holes).

I would like to buy a replacement axle kit. This is what should be in the kit (Image for demonstration purposes only. The image is not of the kit corresponding to the HB M8000. I found this image on google.)


axle
bearings
cones
dustcovers
lockrings

It should not include the

hub shell
quick release


You can generally find the service part numbers by first searching up "_____ exploded view" where the underscores represent the item code (HB-M8000 in your case). You can then identify which service part you need (which in your case is Y2UB98020). Here is the link to the relevant PDF: https://si.shimano.com/de/pdfs/ev/HB-M8000-3868/EV-HB-M8000-3868.pdf. I'll include a screenshot below for permanency's sake.

However, do note that replacing the axle unit on these Shimano front hubs may not be very cost effective (although it depends on exactly why you're trying to replace the axle; see ChrisH's comment). From a quick internet search, the axle unit is available for 35 Euros (~$52 CAD), while an entire brand new hub is $78. Again depending on the specifics, you may be better served putting the replacement money towards a new hub instead--by just replacing the axle unit, you'd still have the old worn bearing cups to deal with, as well as any metal fatigue in the hub shell.

OTOH if you can't rebuild your own wheels, you can add the cost of a wheel build to that of  buying a whole  hub; if you can, there's still the time factor.  Then there are reasons beyond simple wear to replace parts  I've broken cones before (at the back) when the cups were still OK, and there are always bent axles to consider

@ChrisH Good point, I made some edits.
